# Javascript - getting TypeError is not iterable for an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react and I have a component where I am setting a constant with an array of strings:

```
const propsToCheck = ['text', 'type', 'status', 'topic.name', 'class.0.code'];
```

I am sending down the children chain all the way to the component that is using it like this in the function `checkObjectContainsValue` that I import from another file:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state.data = this.transformRows(props.rows.filter(obj => checkObjectContainsValue(obj, props.searchString)(props.propsToCheck)))
  }
```

My tests are failing then because I get an error:

> TypeError: propsToCheck is not iterable

But, I noticed that if I import the `checkObjectContainsValue` function to a parent component where I have `propsToCheck` I don't get the error. But I can't have that function there for other reasons. I have checked the react developer tools and I can see that I am getting the array `propsToCheck` in the child component, so I am not sure why I am getting this error?

This is the function `checkObjectContainsValue`:

```
const checkObjectContainsValue = (obj, value) => (propsToCheck) => {
  for (let prop of propsToCheck) {
    const propToCheckValue = prop.split('.').reduce((currentObject,property) => {
      return currentObject[property];
    }, obj);
    if (propToCheckValue.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

**Update**

If I move the logic to a parent component then everything works fine. This is the example:

```
onSearchChange(event) {
    const searchString = event.target.value;
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const filteredTasks = prevState.tasks.filter(obj => checkObjectContainsValue(obj, searchString)(propsToCheck));
      return {filteredTasks: filteredTasks};
    });
  }
```

Why am I getting this error only when I use this function in the child component?

Comment: is your function definition is like this `func()()` ? as you're calling `checkObjectContainsValue(obj, props.searchString)(props.propsToCheck)` ? does `checkObjectContainsValue` return a function ?

Comment: Yes, checkObjectContainsValue returns a function

Comment: can we see how `checkObjectContainsValue` looks like ?

Comment: On checking in the browser, everything works fine, and I get propsToCheck in the child component as an array

Comment: @Leff you're just passing two arguments to function `checkObjectContainsValue`  whereas it expects three arguments, so the third one becomes `undefined` , which is not iterable

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong copy pasting, I have updated the code with the right example. I was just testing to see if that has anything to do with the fact that it is a currying function.

Answer (score 1):

Your function expects three argument

```
const checkObjectContainsValue = (obj, value, propsToCheck) => {
```

where as you're just passing two argument to function

```
props.rows.filter(obj => checkObjectContainsValue(obj, props.searchString)
```

so the third argument will have a value equal to `undefined` which is not iterable

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong copy pasting, this actually the signature of the function ```const checkObjectContainsValue = (obj, value) => (propsToCheck) => ``` I was just testing if anything would change if I make it a normal function and not a currying one.

Comment: No, ```propToCheckValue``` is a value of a prop, which is a string.

Comment: @Leff can you show how you're sending props to child ?